# MySQL select DISTINCT by highest value

Tags: mysql

I have a table full of magazines, and need to extract the latest unique issue of each magazine.

Ive tried

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    magazine
        FROM
    product p
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        title, MAX(onSale) AS Latest
    FROM
        product
    GROUP BY magazine) groupedp
```

Which returns the distinct magazines , but not the rest of the data I require.

UPDATE:

schema

```
-id----onsale----magazine
  1    1/12/12   Fishing Mag
  2    1/11/12   Fishing Mag
  3    12/03/11  Pencil Sharpening Monthly
  4    1/02/10   Pencil Sharpening Monthly
  5    16/04/09  Homes in the Sky
```

So the result I would like returned would be:

```
 -id----onsale----magazine
   1    1/12/12   Fishing Mag         
   3    12/03/11  Pencil Sharpening Monthly         
   5    16/04/09  Homes in the Sky
```

Comment: You are joining tables on what columns?

Comment: This might be easier to answer if we could see the schema for those two tables.

Comment: There is only one table.

Comment: Yup... Sorry... copy/paste gone bad, still schema would be nice, to know how to perform join table onto itself, and what types of data you're dealing with.

Comment: Schema added, this feels like a really simple question but I can't get the DISTINCT / JOIN part right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    p.*
FROM
        product p
    INNER JOIN
        ( SELECT 
              magazine, MAX(onSale) AS latest
          FROM
              product
          GROUP BY 
              magazine
        ) AS groupedp
      ON  groupedp.magazine = p.magazine
      AND groupedp.latest = p.onSale ;
```

Comment: Thanks. This only returns the very latest though, not the latest of each issue.

Comment: I don't see an `issue` column in your table.

Comment: There isn't I just mean that the table contains issues.

Comment: Where? In which column is this data?

Comment: The table is a table full of 'issues'. So , issue 1 , issue 2 etc although its not defined like that , its defined by 'onsale' .

Comment: So, what is my query returning? Not what you want?

Comment: Yours was only returning 1 result.

Comment: Oh boy, yes, I mixed the `magazine` and the `title` columns. Try this edit.

Comment: an explanation would be incredibly useful for other people like myself who are also interested in accomplishing the same thing :(

Comment: @Anthony this is a 6 years old question but I'll try to update it during the weekend.

Comment: i know. i was just letting you know that an explanation with your answer would have made it 100 times more helpful :)

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT id, MAX(onSale) as latest, magazine
FROM product
GROUP BY magazine
ORDER BY latest DESC
```

Comment: This may show `id` and `onSale` that don't actually match in the table.

Comment: @ypercube is correct. Do you need id for anything? Since it is not being aggregated or included in the GROUP BY clause, it can give you inconsistent results

Comment: @ypercube Jeff You are both right. The results are incorrect , as the id and onSale do not relate to the same .

Comment: I downvoted because you need to add a comment that points out that the id and onSale might not match in the results, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

None of the given answers are correct, as they return an disassociated set of data that does not represent one exact row.  The `id` may not be the `id` from the same row as the `onsale` value.

The following will work:

```
SELECT
    id, onsale, magazine
FROM (
    SELECT
       id, onsale, magazine
    FROM
        product
    ORDER BY
        onsale DESC) AS a
GROUP BY
    magazine
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like what you need:

```
SELECT id, MAX(onsale) AS onsale, magazine FROM magazines GROUP BY magazine ORDER BY onsale DESC;
```

Check it out at:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e78/3

**UPDATE:**
I've changed query a little, to return MAX(onsale)

Comment: Beaten to it by Jeff , literally by seconds!

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the 'rest of data' in the first select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT magazine, "rest of data"
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT title, MAX(onSale) AS Latest 
FROM product 
GROUP BY magazine ) groupedp
```