# How to get dependent data using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the Latest Grade and highest Marks scored in that particular Grade by each student. I do get Latest Grade by using Max function but struggle to get Maximum marks for that Grade. Would really appreciate some thoughts on this...

This is original data

```
+------+-----+-----+
| S_id |Grade|Marks|
+------+-----+-----+
| A1   |   1 |  10 |
| B1   |   2 |  30 |
| B2   |   2 |  20 |
| B2   |   2 |  40 |
| B2   |   3 |  50 |
| B2   |   3 |  20 |
| B3   |   1 |  30 |
| B3   |   1 |  40 |
| B4   |   1 |  30 |
| B4   |   2 |  20 |
+------+-----+-----+
```

This is the expected result

```
+----------------------+------+-----+
| S_id                 | Grade|Marks| 
+----------------------+------+-----+
| A1                   |    1 |  10 |
| B1                   |    2 |  30 |
| B2                   |    3 |  20 |
| B3                   |    1 |  40 |
| B4                   |    2 |  20 |
+----------------------+------+-----+
```

Comment: This help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434124/mysql-select-distinct-by-highest-value

Comment: Thank you for editing mitkosoft

Comment: Your table appears to have no PRIMARY KEY. This is likely to prove problematic further down the road.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Also, if you want the "Latest Grade and highest Marks", wouldn't you expect the mark of 50 to be returned for student B2?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. B2 should have 50. Using MySql 8